# java synchronized method seems not work

Tags: java, multithreading, task, synchronized, executorservice

I have this code that is executed when a file is modified

```
public class WatchQueueReaderTask<Void> extends Task {
...
                protected Object call() throws Exception {
    try {
        // get the first event before looping
        WatchKey key = myWatcher.take();
        while (key != null) {
            // we have a polled event, now we traverse it and 
            // receive all the states from it
            for (WatchEvent event : key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind eventType = event.kind();
                if (eventType == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                     }

                    process(event);

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    System.out.println("WatchQueueReaderTask::call isCancelled");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            key.reset();
            key = myWatcher.take();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ArrayList<WatchFileItem> auxList = threadFileToWatch;
        for (WatchFileItem obj : auxList) {
            if (obj.file != null) {
                try {
                    obj.file.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("errore in file close");
                    Logger.getLogger(WatchQueueReaderTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Stopping thread");
    return null;
   }
 ...
 private synchronized void process(WatchEvent evt) {
 ... }
  }
```

I call it using:

```
    ThreadFactory processingThreadFactoryForRealtime = null;
    ExecutorService processingThreadFactoryForRealtimeExecutor = null;
    WatchQueueReaderTask mywatchQueueReader = null;

    processingThreadFactoryForRealtime = new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                 Thread t = new Thread(r);
                 t.setName("FileWatcherTask");
                 t.setDaemon(true);
                 return t;
             }
    };  

    processingThreadFactoryForRealtimeExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(processingThreadFactoryForRealtime);
    mywatchQueueReader = new WatchQueueReaderTask(realtimePath, watcherServiceForRealtime, fileToWatchForRealtime); 
    processingThreadFactoryForRealtimeExecutor.execute(mywatchQueueReader);
```

The problem is that execute simultaneously multiple methods process() without waiting for the previous is completed.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following.  Is the problem that you have multiple WatchQueueReaderTask instances and you are expecting the process function to be synchronized across all instances?

Comment: You're indentation is a bit wonky, but it looks as if `process()` must be an instance method of `WatchQueueReaderTask`.  If more than one thread is entering `process()` at the same time, then they must be calling process() for different `WatchQueueReaderTask` instances.

Comment: Why is `process()` synchronized?  What invariant are you trying to protect?

Comment: @ james large,  process is an an instance method of WatchQueueReaderTask. process() performs various operations on files,lists and chart, which must be carried out within a critical section to be sure that any process() - one by one - performs the instructions, when the previous one has finished.

Comment: But that can only be a problem if there are mulitple threads calling the same instance of the class. How can that happen?

Comment: @EJP if multiple threads execute simultaneously the process () method I lose the consistency of the data on which the method operates

Comment: @Bubbafat Yes, I want the whole process() method is in a critical section

Comment: Synchronized applies to instances, not types.

Comment: @Bubbafat, could you  explain  better, perhaps with an example?

Comment: A synchronized function is the same as synchronized(this) - this means it is per-instance.  If you have more than one instance of the type then you cannot use a synchronized function to protect a resource that all of the instances share (like a file).  You'd need to use a static synchronized method to achieve that (or any number of synchronization techniques).

Comment: @Bubbafat, thank you very much, would you be so kind to tell me more about " any number of synchronization techniques" ?

Comment: Concurrent programming has many patterns for solving the problem of providing exclusive access to a section of code or piece of data.  In Java the Semaphore class (with a count of 1) is probably your best starting point.  All instances of your class should share the same Semaphore - i.e., it should be a static or singleton or whatever pattern you want - but it should not be an instance member.  A static synchronized function will work like a critical section (which is what you said you wanted, but not what you implemented).